# Possible database error

Tags: support, specific-question

Check out this question, I only went to it because I noticed I have a down vote.

[Location update not working while app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345651/location-update-not-working-while-app-is-in-background/29346529#29346529)

The question is about iOS geo-location but all three answers are about the OpenEars voice recognition software.

Something's not right here...

Comment: Just to be clear: questions asking to recommend software or a framework, or any such off-site resource, are off topic. Just close them, don't try to answer them. Two people did vote to close when it was posted at the time, but the close review queue was frequently overwhelmed and it didn't get enough attention, so those close votes expired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question was [edited in 2016, 10 months after it was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29345651/revisions), and the OP changed the question radically. The OP was question-blocked at the time and tried to work around that block by re-using an old question.

I've rolled back the edit, and closed the question (it was off-topic). I've also deleted it, as it is a low-quality post with too few views to have caught the change earlier.